# Anonymous type exists both dll's error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a function which must query some content and return it to be alerted. Here is the LINQ query:

```
List<DetailedContent> contList = new List<DetailedContent>();
using (entities = new ModerationEntities()) 
        {
            var query = (from mac in entities.ModActionCategories
                         join c in entities.Contents on mac.ActionCategoryId equals c.ActionCategoryId
                         join m in entities.Moderations on mac.ModId equals m.ModId
                         where mac.WillAlert == true
                         select new
                         {
                             c,
                             m.ModerationTitle
                         }
                        ).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.c.ModifiedTime);

            foreach (var item in query) 
            {
                DetailedContent cont = new DetailedContent(item.c);
                cont.ModTitle = item.ModerationTitle;

                contList.Add(cont);
            }

            return contList;

        }
```

It gives exactly this error:

> Results View = The type '<>f__AnonymousType9 < c,ModerationTitle > '
>   exists in both 'ModerationDAL.dll' and 'EntityFramework.dll'

Here is my DetailedContent class definition:

[image]

Comment: Strange error, but a simple workaround would be to use a named type

Comment: @Kaido sorry, but I didn't understand what you mean by "named type".

Comment: See my answer (2) below. I mean avoid the anonymous type in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions

1. select new
   {
     Content = c,
     ModerationTitle = m.ModerationTitle
   }
2. select new Result
       {
             Content = c,
             Title = m.ModerationTitle
       }

where Result is a class defined locally as

```
private class Result
{
   Content Content {get;set;}
   string Title {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the group by is not working as expected but here is the workaround:
Just extend the Linq using `select` statement and create an anonymous object as you want. This just won't happen directly in Group By expression.

```
.Select(s => new { Key =  s.Key, List = s.ToList() }).ToList()
```